# Math inequality proof

Tags: inequality

If $a, b$ are positive real numbers and $a + b = 1$, prove that
$$
\left(a +\frac{1}{a}\right)^2 + \left(b +\frac{1}{b}\right)^2 \geq \frac{25}{2}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: I think that this could help : (a+(1/a))^2 + (b+(1/b))^2 > (1/2)(a+b+(1/a)+(1/b))^2 .. but from where did we get that inequality? Cauchy-Shwartz?

Comment: This question is phrased as a bare question. The best questions include context (where did you find the question? What course is it from?) and a description of what you have already tried. Also, it is considered impolite here to phrase a question in the imperative ("Prove that"). We prefer questions that are phrased as questions.

Answer (score 4):

yes,use $Cuachy-Schwarz$ inequality,we have

$$\left[\left(a+\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^2\right][1+1]\ge\left(a+b+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^2=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^2$$

use $Cauchy-Schwarz $ inequality,we have
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)(a+b)\ge(1+1)^2$$

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life

Answer (score 2):

Replace $b$  by $(1-a)$. Now, compute the derivative of the function; it has only one positive real root at $a=\frac12$. At this point, the second derivative is positive, then $a=\frac12$ corresponds to a minimum and, at this point, the function value is $\frac{25}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \phi(x) = \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2$. Since
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \phi(x) = 2 + \frac{6}{x^4} > 0,$$
$\phi(x)$ is a strictly convex function for $x > 0$. 
By [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we have

$$\left(a + \frac{1}{a}\right)^2 + \left(b + \frac{1}{b}\right)^2 = \phi(a)+\phi(b) \ge 2 \phi(\frac{a+b}{2}) = 2 \left(\frac12 + 2\right)^2 = \frac{25}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's easily seen that, for $a+b=1$ with $a,b\gt0$, the expression

$$ab+{1\over ab}$$

is minimized when $a=b=1/2$.  (In general, $x+{1\over x}$ is smallest when $x$ is as close to $1$ as possible.  If $a+b=1$, the closest $ab$ gets to $1$ is when $a=b=1/2$.)  It follows that

$$\begin{align}
\left(a+{1\over a} \right)^2+\left(b+{1\over b} \right)^2&=a^2+b^2+{1\over a^2}+{1\over b^2}+4\cr
&=(a-b)^2+\left({1\over a}-{1\over b} \right)^2+2\left(ab+{1\over ab}\right)+4\cr
&\ge 2\left(ab+{1\over ab}\right)+4\cr
&\ge 2\left({1\over4}+{1\over1/4}\right)+4\cr
&={25\over2}
\end{align}$$